# How can I mount a dd clone of a btrfs disk?

Tags: mount, btrfs, disk-image

I cloned a harddisk with btrfs with dd. Now I want to mount the cloned drive, while the "original" is still mounted:

```
mount /dev/sdc /mnt/tmp
mount: /mnt/tmp: mount(2) system call failed: File exists.
```

A `btrfsck /dev/sdc` doesn't show any errors. How can I mount that disk?

Comment: The clone will have information on volume names for example, that will collide with the original, if they are mounted at the same time. That's why you get the error `File exists`. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do, we can help you. In the meantime you can check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/189616/backup-clone-a-btrfs-partition) or [this](https://github.com/mwilck/btrfs-clone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

btrfs is a multi-device (capable) filesystem, so it needs some way to keep track of which devices are part of a given filesystem. In fact, if you have multiple devices, you give just one to mount, and btrfs finds the others itself.

It does this by the UUID of the filesystem, which of course is now the same on your copy. btrfs stores that UUID many times; `btrfstune -u /dev/sdc` should change all of them (but may take a bit, as it has to rewrite a bunch of metadata). On relatively new kernels ([patch from December 2018](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7239ff4b2be8ec0c3160da7fdd1475785fdb4cb9)), `btrfstune -m /dev/sdc` ought to work as well, without having to rewrite all the metadata. Note that some people have reported corruption with these options, but you're already working on a copy.

### Important warning!

Please read the [btrfs Gotchas](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas), in particular the [warning about block-level copies](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Block-level_copies_of_devices). Having two copies of one of the filesystems block devices around is inviting the kernel to use the wrong one (because they have the same filesystem UUID, so as far as it can tell, are the same device), which — if it happens — will likely **destroy** *both* of them. **Including your original.** (Think of what happens if you have a two-device filesystem, with devices A1 and B1. You make a copy of A1 as A2. Now when the kernel mounts the filesystem, it might use A1 and B1 as expected. Or it might use A2 and B1. And that might switch on each mount, meaning half of the filesystem might have "lost" all the writes since the last mount).

Thankfully, the kernel noticed your attempt to mount the clone and stopped you.

### What do to instead

Any of:

- Copy the image to a file (and do not set up a loopback device to it). Work on the copy on another computer (with a loopback device) or in a VM. Do not let one kernel see both copies until you're sure the filesystem UUID has been changed.
- Use `tar`, `btrfs-send`, etc. to create a copy to a new filesystem, with a different filesystem UUID.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer! I suspected that it might be something related to IDs but didn't know the danger. Since I just wanted to have the copy as kind of a security copy, I will just remove it and put it aside, hoping I'll never need it.

Comment: @MarkusGrunwald for that, consider either tar (if you don't need an image backup) or partclone (which can do things like not copy free space).